# cuda 9.2 curand_init extremely slow

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a program where I generate arrays with random elements using cuda. Since I upgraded from cuda 9.1 to cuda 9.2, the time it takes do that has gone up from a fraction of a second (about 0.1s) to almost two minutes (without changing any of the code). The problem seems to be the curand_init() function, as the rest is running at about the same speed. Was there a change I missed in the library, is this a bug or is it a problem with my code?
This is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#define cudaErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
    {
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
        {
        std::cerr << "cudaAssert: " << cudaGetErrorString(code) << " " << file << ": " << line << std::endl;
        if (abort) exit(code);
        }
    }

__global__
void setup_curand_state (curandState *state, int seed, int dim)
    {
    int index = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    if (index < dim)
        curand_init(seed, index, 0, &state[index]);
    }

__global__
void set_random (float* to, curandState* curand_state, int dim)
    {
    int index = threadIdx.x+ blockIdx.x* blockDim.x;
    if (index < dim)
        to [index] = curand_normal (&curand_state[index]);
    }

int main () {

int dim = 100000;
float *data;
cudaErrchk (cudaMallocManaged ((void**) &data, dim * sizeof (float)));

curandState* curand_state;
cudaErrchk (cudaMalloc (&curand_state, (dim * sizeof (curandState))));
setup_curand_state <<<(dim + 1023) / 1024, 1024>>> (curand_state, time(NULL), dim);
cudaErrchk (cudaDeviceSynchronize());
set_random <<<(dim + 1023) / 1024, 1024>>> (data, curand_state, dim);

cudaFree (data);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given the downvotes (not mine) and close votes, I would suggest to make a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the problem / slow down.

Comment: Apparently, updating cuda through apt silently broke the install. Code compiled for 9.1 would still work, but around 100/1000 times slower. Reinstalling nvidia-cuda-toolkit solved the error

Answer (score 1):

Answered by mrBonobo in the comment above:

> Apparently, updating cuda through apt silently broke the install. Code
>   compiled for 9.1 would still work, but around 100/1000 times slower.
>   Reinstalling nvidia-cuda-toolkit solved the error